# List of preprocessor directives (#defines) compiled using a Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, c-preprocessor, avr

What command can I use to view a list of all `#define` directives (not macros) active after the preprocessor runs on a set of files compiled with a Makefile and make? I found that `cpp -dM foo.h` will simply output the list of defines to stdout, but I don't see how to get make to do this.

Also, I am using avr-gcc and avr-g++, but this may be irrelevant.

Comment: `using a Makefile` What does it mean? Do you have to see that while `make`-ing?

Comment: no, I just need the dependency graph to be taken into account so if I include a file that has defines in it, these are reflected. One thing I have tried is running make -n to get the underlying script that calls avr-g++ and then i tried adding the -dM option to the avr-g++ line, but it didnt output any defines :(

Answer (score 0):

Ah I've figured it out. Use make -n to generate the make commands, and after the avr-g++ command add -dM -E and find the output in the file specified after -o. What I didnt realize earlier is that the .o file, which is normally a binary, would now contain plaintext output.

Comment: You should accept your own answer if you've found the solution.